# AFNetworking Error: "Expected status code in (200-299), got 404"

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, rest, afnetworking

My code:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http:testurl.com"];
AFHTTPClient *httpClient = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:url];

NSString *email = @"test@test.com";
NSString *password = @"test";

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        email, @"email",
                        password, @"password",
                        nil];

[httpClient postPath:@"/myobject" parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    NSString *responseStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Request Successful, response '%@'", responseStr);
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"[HTTPClient Error]: %@", error.localizedDescription);
}];
```

Even though I know the server is expected a POST I tried GET and PUT too and still received the same error. I also have checked the URL 100 times. Any ideas on what's causing the error?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the URL made by putting `http:testurl.com` and `/myobject` together in your browser. 404 means that page or resource does not exist.

Try also moving the slash to the baseUrl, i.e. baseURL to `http://testurl.com/` and postPath to `myobject` see [this issue](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/issues/471)

Answer (score 1):

Your base URL is malformed.

Change this: `"http:testurl.com"`

To this: `"http://testurl.com"`